# How to install an rpm through puppet and provider as yum

Tags: puppet

I have an RPM, which I am keeping in repo.

Now I need to install the rpm via puppet. I dont have any dependency for that rpm. Currently I am using script

```
package { "application":
        provider => rpm,
       source => "http://10.20.51.163/repo/calculator$calculator_version.rpm",
        install_options => ['-ivh --prefix=/opt/'],
        ensure => [$calculator_version],
}
```

But I want to change this code and use provider as yum. How can I do that ? Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can add the repo with puppet like this :

```
yumrepo { "pp-centos-7-local":
     baseurl => "http://localrepo.example.com/localrepo",
     descr => "centos-7-local",
     enabled => 1,
}
```

And then you can use a much simpler `package` resource:

```
package { yourpackagename:
     ensure => present,
     # require => Yumrepo["pp-centos-7-local"],
}
```

The `require` line should make sure the repo is added before the package, as otherwise it *might* happen that the package doesn't get installed on the first run as the repo isn't present yet for `yum`.

Answer (score 0):

May be , if you want to do something quicker and don't want to add rpm in yumrepo, you can consider this option as well.

```
  exec {'download_install_epel_rpm' :
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
    command => '/usr/bin/wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm -P /tmp/;rpm -ivh /tmp/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm; rm -f /tmp/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm',
    unless  => 'rpm -qa | grep epel-release'
  }
```